# how to get the text of a button in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

so I have this simple window:

[image: the form]

so What I want to do basically is that, I want to choose let's say dataset 1 and Random forest and then press submit. when I press submit I have a function that will just check the text on both buttons ( it will check dataset 1 and Random forest) then it will return the appropriate action. so basically my problem is with the text I am not able to read it.

I have tried to use cget in tkinter but I was not able to work it out properly.

my code is:

```
win =  Tk()

win.geometry("400x600")
win.configure(background="cyan")
win.title("Registration Form")

title = Label(win, text="Ensemble Methods", bg="gray", width="300", height="2", fg="white", font = ("Calibri 20 bold italic underline")).pack()

dataset_1 = Button(win, text="dataset 1", width="12",height="1",activebackground="violet", bg="Pink",command=printit,font = ("Calibri 12 ")).place(x=20, y=200)
dataset_2 = Button(win, text="dataset 2", width="12",height="1",activebackground="violet", bg="Pink",command=printit,font = ("Calibri 12 ")).place(x=150, y=200)
dataset_3 = Button(win, text="dataset 3", width="12",height="1",activebackground="violet", bg="Pink",command=printit,font = ("Calibri 12 ")).place(x=280, y=200)

radio = StringVar()

random_forest = Radiobutton(win, text="Random Forest",bg="cyan",variable=radio,value="Male",font = ("Verdana 12")).place(x=20,y=340)
AdaBoost = Radiobutton(win, text="Ada Boost",bg="cyan",variable=radio,value="Female",font = ("Verdana 12")).place(x=280,y=340)


submit = Button(win, text="Submit", width="12",height="1",activebackground="violet", bg="Pink",command=printit,font = ("Calibri 12 ")).place(x=240, y=540)

win.mainloop()
```

and the function that will take the text and do the action is:

```
def printit():
    
    my_text = dataset_1.cget('text')
    
    if my_text == 'dataset 1':
        Label(win,text="yes",fg="blue",bg="yellow",font = ("Calibri 10 bold")).place(x=12,y=780)
```

Comment: You've got an answer explaining how to make the `.cget()` work, but I'm going to question what you hoped to accomplish with it.  There's nothing in the code you posted that can change the text of the button, so the text you retrieve from it is always going to be the same.  You need to give each Button its own unique `command=` function if you want them to perform different actions.

Comment: I don't want to create a function for each and every button I want the same submit button when its triggered it checks the text of the buttons that I pressed on them and it will perform an action using if else inside the function I think it can work

Comment: You are checking the text of `dataset_1`, specifically.  That will always be `"dataset 1"`, regardless of which button was clicked.

Comment: @jasonharper how can I check the text of each one? so for example if I pressed on dataset 2 how can I make the program know that I pressed on that so when I press on the submit button it will perform a different action

Comment: You tell that you pressed the dataset 2 button by giving it a distinct `command=` function; there's no other way in Tkinter to distinguish buttons.  That function could be a single line, that calls a common function with a distinct parameter that identifies the particular button.

Answer (score 0):

`place()` method always returns `None` therefore `dataset_1` variable stores `None` value.
You need to use

```py
dataset_1 = Button(win, text="dataset 1", width="12",height="1",activebackground="violet", bg="Pink",command=printit,font=("Calibri 12 "))
dataset_1.place(x=20, y=200)
```

Instead of

```py
dataset_1 = Button(win, text="dataset 1", width="12",height="1",activebackground="violet", bg="Pink",command=printit,font = ("Calibri 12 ")).place(x=20, y=200)
```

To store a reference to `Button` object in the variable and then access it.

Comment: I get what you mean and I changed it accordingly but still doesn't work whenever I press the submit button :/

Comment: You written `Label(win, text="yes", fg="blue", bg="yellow", font=("Calibri 10 bold")).place(x=12, y=780)` and set `y=780` but your window has only 600px height.

Comment: Though, I recommend passing argument to the function and checking it, that way the buttons can be `None` too

Comment: @CoolCloud how can I make the submit button know which dataset I have chosen?

Comment: `Random Forest` or `Ada Boost`?

Comment: @mouhamad `command=lambda: printit('dataset1')` while `def printit(val):` and you can check for value using `if val == 'dataset1':`. But do note the answer mentioned above will solve your problem anyway.